# Query string automatically added as an array

Tags: php

I've just noticed an odd behavior with the $_SERVER global variable on my server (Ubuntu 14.04/Apache 2.2).

Ever since I get a specific $_SERVER variable (such as $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']), the url query string (if any) is automatically added as an array at the end of each variable value.

Says I have the following GET request:

> www.domaine.com/index.php?id=45&user=john

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'];
```

I get:

```
gzip, deflate, sdcharray(2) {
["id"]=>

    string(2) "45",
  ["user"]=>
  string(4) "john"
}
```

Where does that array come from ?
Is it generated by PHP, Apache, and how to get rid of it ?

Thanks for advance.

Comment: This might seem like a silly question, but are you sure that the `echo` statement is doing this? It looks like a `var_dump($_GET)` output. If `HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING` really has the contents of `var_dump($_GET)` inside of it, then something is very wrong with your server. I'd search your code for any `var_dump` call and comment them out till you find the error.

Comment: The content from `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING']` is from the header request (See: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: 2nd'd, check for `var_dump($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])` thats what it looks like

Comment: God, you're damn right. 
My code is a bit messy for now (development phase) and I've just found out into another php file a (nasty) var_dump 
which cause the problem. 
Case closed. Sorry for the inconvenience :)

Comment: @Duddy67 This is another good reason to use `var_dump` instead of `echo` when testing (as I can see you do with arrays). It would output `string(19) "gzip, deflate, sdch"` and it'd be very obvious that it wasn't where the second output happened.

Comment: You are absolutely right. From now on I'll use var_dump anywhere.